# Biblatex parencite command with dot right before the closing parenthesis

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

My university likes to have some interesting cite rules and to comply to them I would need citing commands to produce 
`<author> (<year>)`, `(<author> <year>)` and `(<author> <year>.)` To do this I looked into natbib and found `\citet` and `\cite` that closely resembled what I needed. With a little fiddling I managed to get them closer to what I needed. The problem came with the dot and the comma in the middle

Here is what I currently have.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,natbib,citetracker=true,%
maxcitenames=1,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{cite/citedb.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \addspace\&\space}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\clearfield{namehash}}}

\xpatchbibmacro{cite}
  {\printnames{labelname}}
  {\ifciteseen
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\printnames[][1-99]{labelname}}}
  {}
  {}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}
  {\printnames{labelname}}
  {\ifciteseen
    {\printnames{labelname}}
    {\printnames[][1-99]{labelname}}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\citet{foo}

\citet{foo}

\citep{foo}

\cited{foo}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What this currently produces me is

Foo, Bar & Baz (xyz)

Foo et al., (xyz)

(Foo et al., xyz)

So how can I get that comma go away in `\citep` before the year and also create the needed command ?`\cited`? with the dot at the end like this?

(Foo et al. xyz.)

Comment: If my answer below helped you, please consider up-voting and accepting it. If it doesn't quite do what you want, don't hesitate to comment and ask for improvement.

Comment: Thank you It worked perfectly, I'm just working on multiple projects at the moment and just now got the chance to test this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the comma go away with

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

Indeed it is the `natbib` compatibility mode (see `blx-natbib.def`) that makes this change necessary, the default is to use a space only.

---

The period in `\cited` you can get with

```
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibparensperiod}[1]{\mkbibparens{#1\addperiod}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\darencite}[\mkbibparensperiod]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cited}{\darencite}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to use the `natbib` compatibility mode, you can use the `biblatex` names for the commands: `\textcite` and `\parencite`.